# Loading json Data in angular with .success

Tags: angularjs, json, promise

I am working with the pro angularjs Book to learn angular but have stumbled quite early on: I can't get data from a json file to appear. Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myApp = angular.module("demo", []);
        myApp.controller("demoCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
            var promise = $http.get("todo.json");
            promise.success(function(data) {
                $scope.todos = data;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="demoCtrl">
    <div class="panel">
        <h1>To Do</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <tr><td>Action</td><td>Done</td></tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in todos">
                <td>{{item.action}}</td>
                <td>{{item.done}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the json file:

```
[{ "action": "Buy Flowers", "done": false },
 { "action": "Get Shoes", "done": false },
 { "action": "Collect Tickets", "done": true },
 { "action": "Call Joe", "done": false }]
```

The table appears with no content.
I read that `.success` is outdated and used `.then` instead, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module("demo", []);
    myApp.controller("demoCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
        var promise = $http.get("todo.json");
        promise.then(function(data) {
            $scope.todos = data;
        }, function() {
            alert('No Todos');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now I get 6 empty rows in my table. Please help :)

Comment: `.then` wraps the response in an object. pull it out with `$scope.todos = data.data;`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for the quick response!